# How to pass arguments to controller from routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller action as follows

```
def method params
  //work with params
end
```

and I want to pass arguments to the controller from routes.rb

```
get '/link' , to: 'controller#method'
```

and I don't want parameters to appear in URL.

Comment: What kind of arguments are you trying to pass? Where do they come from? It's very likely that you've chosen the wrong solution for whatever your underlying problem is. There is no reason to want to add extra arguments from inside `routes.rb` to your controller method, `routes.rb` shouldn't contain any logic.

Comment: @meagar i have a set of URLs that has common action with difference between them being arguments so i wanted to pass arguments from routes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
get '/link' , to: 'controller#method', as: :my_link
```

Use route helper to pass param

```
<%= link_to 'My Link', my_link_path(param_1: "abc", param_2: "xyz")%>
```

url will look like

```
http://localhost:300/link?param_1=abc&&param_2=xyz
```

At controller#method you can get these params as

```
params[:param_1] = "abc"
params[:param_2] = "xyz"
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I don't want the arguments to appear in URL

Comment: in that case you need to make post type request.